# Is it possible to control the embedded video player within youtube.com?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api

While browsing a youtube.com page is it possible to control the video player through javascript on that page? E.g. get the `embed` element and send it a "pause" message. 
Could it be possible to use the [Youtube JS API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference)?

I have managed to do something similar by browsing the video as HTML 5 (using the &html5=1 query parameter), then getting the `video` element and calling `play()` or `pause()`. However not all youtube videos will show in HTML 5, some load as SWF even when requesting HTML 5.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Okay so given `var player` is the `embed` object, the functions such as `player.playVideo()` work, however I cannot seem to get events to work. E.g. `player.addEventListener('onStateChange', myFunc)` never calls `myFunc`. In fact the SWF object seems to swallow all events including 'click'.

Is there any way I can listen for when a user manually plays or pauses, without polling `player.getPlayerState()`?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just in the link you posted to the JS API. More precisely, [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_controls).

Excerpt:

> Playing a video
>
> player.playVideo():Void
> Plays the currently cued/loaded video. The final player state after this function executes will be playing (1).

Comment: I wasn't sure what `player` was a reference to, but I found this works if `player` is the `embed` object. I was using chrome's console hints to tell me what methods the object had, but those methods do not show. Are they defined further up the proto chain somewhere?